# How do I set a minimum of an incremental id in laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to set my incremental id to start counting from 1000. How can do that

my animal table

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('animals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('type_id')->index();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('placeOfBirth');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DB::statement()` can be used to execute any single SQL statement you need.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('animals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('type_id')->index();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('placeOfBirth');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
        });

    // Here's the magic
    \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE animals AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;');
}
```

Check this for [more info](https://laraveldaily.com/set-auto-increment-start-laravel-migrations/)

Comment: It is bringing an error while running the migrate fresh